# Corrupted file error after creating Attachment from data(attachment) from Other SalesForce Instance through Rest Api

Tags: rest-api, attachment, blob

We are facing issue when we create Attachment record in Apex, using the data that we get from Rest Api from another instance. Tried with Blob.ValueOf(responsebody), EncodingUtil.base64decode(responsebody), where as response body is in string.

Please suggest. Thank you in advance.

Shrivaths

Comment: Please post your complete code and the errors (if any)

Comment: Hi Gaurav, 
Thank you for showing interest.  This issue has been resolved by making use of getBodyasBlob() method. As I was trying to get the data in string first and then I was trying to convert to blob and insert the attachment. Now its working fine, but wondering wahts the limit if we use getBodyasBlob(), is there any limitation? Or is there any other solution for that?
Thanks,
Shrivaths